# Windows audio constantly mutes/unmutes

Tags: windows-10, audio

Running Windows 10. My audio mutes, unmutes, mutes, unmutes erratically. Sometimes it toggles a few times per second, while other times it goes for several minutes without changing. There's no rhyme or reason to it. I've tried reinstalling the drivers, with no success.

I have no reason to believe this is a hardware issue, but who knows?

One possible clue: Windows doesn't recognize my frontboard audio jacks unless I set them up to be AC97 (they should be HD).

What should I try next?

Comment: Can you test without your keyboard? Maybe the mute button on it is faulty.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I can certainly try! I don't believe I have any audio buttons on that keyboard though.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be to confirm that this definitely isn't a hardware issue. Whatever your normal sources of audio output are, disable their drivers and plug in something else, such as headphones, earphones, or an external speaker. If you still get the issue there, then it's probably neither your audio hardware nor their drivers.

Comment: If I disable all audio drivers, wouldn't the computer be incapable of producing sound through those ports? (Of course, the BIOS should have no issues talking with the [PC speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker)...but I hope it's not a motherboard issue!)

Comment: @jvriesem I'm pretty sure that a new driver will appear when your put a new audio device in, like a pair of earphones.

Answer (score 0):

I think the keyboard mute button is stuck? Please check it or something which can control mute/unmute is interfering. For that, go into settings and disabled that button.

Comment: My keyboard does not have a volume control button. (I know keys *can* be remapped in theory, so any key can trigger any event, but have no reason to expect this behavior on a <1 month old clean install of Windows 10.) As far as I know, the only hardware capable of controlling the audio is the front panel and the motherboard connection on the back of the tower.